# Connecting to a server using ftp

Tags: shell

I want to connect to one remote server and I want to fetch some files from the same. How can I do this with ftp (or sftp)? 
I dont want to do it using any software other than putty.

Comment: Have you looked for FTP commands? https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html

Comment: Parden If I am wrong..But how we will get the machinename/hostname of the server?Because to connect to other server, ftp "hostname/machinename /ip" i need to type ..And what are the prerequisites for two systems to connect through FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Putty usually comes with pscp tools, so you can use it to copy files over SSH:

```
pscp user@host:/path/to/remote_file .
pscp local_file user@host:/remote/dir
```

Comment: I didnt get it :(..Can  u elaborate more? And I want to copy files between different servers..

Comment: You do not have to connect to server in order to copy files from there. Just look at scp on unix or pscp on windows and use it as showed above.